# MySQL query datetime default

Tags: mysql

I've got the SQL query below that seems to be throwing an error but I', really stuck in where the syntax error is.  I think it's on the field5 but I'm not 100% if I'm using default datetime correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (field0 int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
field2 DATETIME NOT NULL,
field3 int(1) unsigned default 0,
field4 int(10) NOT NULL,
field5 DATETIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
```

Can anyone whose better at SQL see where the syntax error is? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable30(
  `key` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  field2 DATETIME NOT NULL,
  field3 INT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
  field4 INT(10) NOT NULL,
  field5 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

It is better to rename `key` field.
INT(1) - should it be like this INT(11)?

Answer (score 3):

Field 5 - TIMESTAMP is a type and so is DATETIME, use one or the other not both.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: this explains the solution better than the chosen answer. I know Tommy posted first, but I voted for this one because it already had a vote and it needs to be near the top.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Datetime and Timestamp, you have to choose one.